# Error: socket hang up at process._tickCallback (node.js:364:17)

Tags: node.js

I have written a node process which would call itself with a different set of payload data through the localhost using request function.

```
var options = {
    'method' : 'POST',
    'uri' : http://localhost:3030/myPath,
    'json' : payload
};
request(options);
```

I am using the postman to fire the original request at "http://localhost:3030/myPath", which in turn would modify the payload and call itself again using the request method described above. And this step should continue for some time. But after 1/2 iterations, node is throwing the following error:

```
Error: socket hang up
    at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:209:15)
    at Socket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:294:23)
    at emitNone (events.js:72:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:166:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:905:12)
    at doNTCallback2 (node.js:450:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:364:17)
```

Can anyone please let me know, what I have done wrong here ?